# Django ManyToMany Creating Duplicate Relationship for Self Referential Attribute

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I've got a model that looks something like this:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    sub_sessions = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

Now when I do something like:

```
session_1 = Session.objecte.get(id=1)
session_2 = Session.objects.get(id=2)
session_1.sub_sessions.add(session_2)
```

What happens is that a relationship is created such that `session_2` is in `session_1`'s `sub_sessions` field, but `session_1` is also in `session_2`'s `sub_sessions` field.

I imagine this makes sense at some level being a `ManyToManyField` relationship, but it's really not what I want. I only want `session_2` to be in `session_1`'s `sub_sessions` field, but not the other way around.

I suppose I can instead create a `ForeignKey` relationship, but it'll just break a few of my current coding implementations and I'd really love to have some sort of a way to make this work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the symmetrical property what you are looking for?

```
class Session(models.Model):
    sub_sessions = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False)
```

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical)